# Setup Kestrel with RequireCertificate for single controller/endpoints

Tags: ssl, .net-core, identityserver4, client-certificates, kestrel

Am i out of luck or is there an option to specify that only a single path/endpoint should require client certificate ?

The scenario:
IdentityServer4 gives our users the option to sign in multiple ways (Username/Password, Azure AD or ClientCertificate)

The first two are working as intended, but the certificate paths does not prompt the user for his/her certificate, i know its possible with IIS but we want to run this using Kestrel.

If i setup the projects kestrel setting to require cert all endpoints requires it, this ruins the user experience when signing in with username/password og azure ad.

Are there any options for setting only out localhost/certificate path to require certificate and then in turn prompt the user to provide their cert when being redirected to that paths endpoints if there is no cert present in the request?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by setting up two hosts, and capturing the request in the certificate challange endpoint and checking the connection, if there's no certificate present AND the connection is using the non-requirecert connection i redirected the context to the right connection and was then prompted to supply the cert and login works as intended.